# how to check which cuda is being used by tensorflow gpu

Tags: tensorflow

In my laptop there are three versions of `cuda`, 8.0, 9.0 and 10.0 installed, all of which are configured in the environment `path`. When I use `tensorflow-gpu 2.0.0`, how to know which version of `cuda` is to be deployed, without considering that the present version of tensorflow is only compatible with cuda 10.0. Is there any way to print the information on python console?

Answer (score -1):

I found answers here [get the CUDA and CUDNN version on windows with Anaconda installe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52410484/get-the-cuda-and-cudnn-version-on-windows-with-anaconda-installe):

```
from tensorflow.python.platform import build_info as tf_build_info
print(tf_build_info.cuda_version_number)
#10.0
print(tf_build_info.cudnn_version_number)
#7
```