# Show the CUDA Runtime version in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu, cuda

I would like to know the CUDA Runtime version that is being used by tensorflow.

I found two cuda installations on my machine (Ubuntu 18.04), and I am not sure which version is currently being used. Weirdly, no environment variable like `PATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or `CUDA_HOME` is set, but I am still able to launch trainings on GPUs.

Is there a way to force tensorflow to tell which CUDA version it is using, like a `cudaRuntimeGetVersion()` would do?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52410593/1782792) of the question marked as duplicate works on recent TensorFlow versions.

Comment: Thanks it worked! I'll edit my question to add the way of doing it